# WSPBuilder verbose tracelevel

Tags: wspbuilder

Don't know if I'm missing something blindingly obvious here, but I'm using wspbuilder.exe from the commandline and would like verbose output.

However, if I do `WSPBuilder.exe -TraceLevel Verbose`, all I get is:

```
WSPBuilder

Version: 0.9.9.0728 Created by Carsten
Keutmann GPL License 2007
Building the solution - please wait
Saving the Manifest.xml file 
Creating the Cabinet.ddf file 
Creating the WSP file 
Done!
```

which doesn't seem very verbose.  It's also the exact same output I get for `WSPBuilder.exe -TraceLevel Info`.  Is that all there is?

Comment: My mistake -- I was simply running the command in a project that didn't have any 12 hive files or any other files to actual include in the WSP.  If you have tracelevel verbose, it outputs what files it is adding to the wsp.

Comment: Can you please move your comment to an answer? This way, you can mark it as the correct answer and allow other people to contribute. See also, [Posting answers to your own question](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138/posting-answers-to-your-own-question/141#141).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake -- I was simply running the command in a project that didn't have any 12 hive files or any other files to actual include in the WSP. If you have tracelevel verbose, it outputs what files it is adding to the wsp.